# GitHub workflow, confused about toJson and fromJson. I'm doing a JSON ouput and reading it with fromJson, why I get this error?

Tags: github-actions

```
on:
    push:

jobs:
    matrix:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: Setup
        outputs:
            php-versions: ${{ toJson('["7.4.10", "5.6.13", "7.4.33", "8.1"]') }}

    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: matrix
        strategy:
            fail-fast: false
            matrix:
                version: ${{ fromJson(needs.matrix.outputs.php-versions) }}
```

> Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'build'. .github/workflows/test.yaml (Line: 17, Col: 26): Unexpected value '["7.4.10", "5.6.13", "7.4.33", "8.1"]'

Why I can't simply `toJSON` in the `matrix` job and then `fromJson` to feed the `build` job? I'm pretty sure isn't a limitation but my fault. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) says:

> `toJSON`: returns a pretty-print JSON representation of value

> `fromJson`: Returns a JSON object or JSON data type for value

Comment: `toJson` doesn't work with hardocded string literal, `fromJson` does. That `matrix` job doesn't seem to be reflecting the actual use case. How is that `php-versions` output being set by that job?

Comment: Your issue seems related to the way you're creating the JSON, as stated by Azeem. I made an example [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester84.yml) using bash to create the list as output, and then share it to another job. The workflow run can be found [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/5422424081) if you want to have a look.